# why angular Universal Can't install to existing angular project

Tags: angular, angular-ssr

i Using package manager: npm
√ Found compatible package version: @nguniversal/express-engine@15.2.0.
√ Package information loaded.

The package @nguniversal/express-engine@15.2.0 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
√ Packages successfully installed.
Path "tsconfig.server.json" does not exist.

I want add server side rendering to my existing angular project. that created with  angular version is 15.1.4

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install version `15.1.0` into your project

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine@15.1.0
```

[npmjs.org](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nguniversal/express-engine/v/15.1.0?activeTab=versions)

Comment: its not working, same error